# Installing ubuntu server on laptop - can't recognize wifi card

Tags: wireless, system-installation, wifi-hardware-switch

I am trying to install ubuntu server on my laptop and it doesn't recognize the wifi card on start of the installation. And i think it's because it is turned off. How can i turn it on without hardware switch?

#### update

I have managed to install it without wifi (that is my only nic) and turned it on after, but i don't have internet now. How to connect to my wifi network from command line?

I found that i need this `wpasupplicant` but i can't install it without internet. Maybe this can be found on iso image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, if your notebook does not have a hardware switch to enable/disable WiFi, there probably is an option in the BIOS or UEFI to do it.

Now that you managed to install the system and have a working WiFi card, , you should use `wpa_supplicant` to setup the network. To do this, you edit the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` so that it holds the information necessary to connect to your network. Examples can be found in the [wpa_supplicant man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf), a minimal one would look similar to this:

```
network={
    ssid=YourSSID
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk=your_very_secret_passphrase
}
```

Additionally, you need to set your `/etc/network/interfaces` to use the configuration for `wpa_supplicant`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Assuming your WiFi card is the network interface `wlan0`. Now, issue `ifup wlan0` on the command line, and you should be fine.

Edit: If you do not have `wpa_supplicant` installed, you can download the `.deb` package on another machine and install from a USB device or whatever possibility you have to move files onto that machine. The package and its dependencies can be found in the [Ubuntu package archive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wpasupplicant).

Comment: but i dont have wpasupplicant. i cant install it without internet! Or can I?

Comment: just to make something clear: my vision about wpasupplicant is that it is some kind of software that you need to install before setting up the interfaces and writing into `/etc/network/interfaces` is this true or false?

Comment: wpasupplicant is the software module that handles WPA/WPA2 authentication in wireless connections. So, yes, you need it to set up the connection using `/etc/network/interfaces`. You edit the two config files, and then issue the `ifup wlan0` command, and it uses the network definition from `/etc/network/interfaces` along with the authentication info from wpasupplicant

Comment: Just as i have expected. BUT i have installed the server without internet and i can't install wpasupplicant because i don't have internet connection. What can i do now to solve the problem??

Comment: As the edit says: Download the packages manually on another machine (like the one you are currently posting from) and transport them to the other machine via some means of USB storage, a SATA disk, or burn them to a CD. You could probably also use the medium you used to install the system.

Comment: Thanks to you i have solved the problem, and I am very sorry that i got downvoted :(